Parent to Armature the child objects have a grayed out copy inside the hierarchy instead of being inside the hierarchy
I set these 4 object's parent to an armature but for some reason they appear like this in the hierarchy.
The rig works fine in Blender but when I import the FBX file in a game engine the bone assigned to these objects doesn't affect them

I already tried clearing all their parents and re-parenting these objects to the armature but nothing changes.
Is there any way to fix this?

I just found another post similar to this in stack overflow where they just had their objects outside of the collection where the armature is located
so I just moved the objects in the correct collection and it worked
solution post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74463663/parenting-duplicating-and-graying-out-child-objects-in-outliner
